# Why does strlen() work and my approach doesnt?

Tags: c

I have the following function:

```
void print_out_reversed(char string[])
{
    int index = strlen(string);
    printf("%i\n", index);

    while (string[index] != '\0')
        index--;

    for (int i = index; i >= 0; i--)
        putchar(string[i]);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

This function works fine after I deleted the line

```
int index = sizeof(string) / sizeof(string[0])
```

and replaced it by

```
strlen(string)
```

But why? I learned that if you want to find out the length of an array, you have to divide array by array[0]. In my old version he always printed out that the index is eight no matter which string I have entered. I cant figure out why.I know that strlen() ignores the elements after "\0", but suppose that I want the total size of a char array.

Comment: What do you hope to accomplish with `while (string[index] != '\0') index--;`?

Comment: "to find out the length of an array, you have to divide array by array[0]" --> is true.  Yet `char string` in `print_out_reversed(char string[])` is **not** an array.

Comment: Well, what is it then? And how do I give an array to a function properly, so that I can do this operation?

Comment: Vengeancos, Hmmm, the duplicate, being a C++ one , does not well apply here.  In any case, the goal is to reverse a _string_.   The _size_ of that array is not needed here at all.  `void print_out_reversed(char string[]) {
    int index = strlen(string);
    for (int i = index; i > 0; ) { i--;
        putchar(string[i]);}
    putchar('\n');
}` should do it.

Comment: But how to give a char array instead of a pointer to a function? The syntax is that of a char array, so why it is not handled as one internally? I tried to learn C because some programmers say that C has a clear syntax, but I'm almost ready to say that the opposite is true. C has a confusing trap syntax that can only be understood in part with strange edge knowledge.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
void print_out_reversed(char string[]) { }
```

`string` decays to a **pointer**, it's not an array, hence when you do `sizeof(string)` it results in **size of pointer** not size of an array.

This

```
int index = sizeof(string) / sizeof(string[0])
```

results in `4/1` i.e `4` on `32-bit` system.

Whereas when you do

```
int index = strlen(string);
```

`strlen()` returns the **numbers of bytes** in the `string` excluding `\0`. Also `strlen()` return type is `size_t`. For e.g

```
size_t index = strlen(string);
```

Comment: "`string` decays to a pointer" --> Not quite.  `char string[]` in `print_out_reversed(char string[])` is not an array, bit a pointer, so no decay occurs.  `char string[]` just looks like an array. `sizeof(string)` is simply the size of a pointer.